# Getting Permission denied to access property "document"

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm not clear why i'm getting this error, when loading the HTML file in the web browser from different domain, `I have not set any X-Frame-Options header in the HTTP response`

> Permission denied to access property "document"

This is my header information of the server

```
curl -I zariga.com
```

The Output

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 17:17:57 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=656D65705C14A5B643B6EA281DF03A8D; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

My HTML iFrame file

```
<html>
<script>

function myFunction() {

    document.domain = "zariga.com";

var i = document.createElement('iframe');

i.setAttribute('id', 'i');
i.setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;');
i.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.zariga.com/');
i.onload = function(){
alert(i.contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('syc')[0].value);
 alert(2);
};

document.body.appendChild(i);

}

</script>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the current document.domain ? could you check that in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the content of an iframe this way. Otherwise, you could easily inject other websites and steal a visitor's accounts.

If you have access to the website included in the iframe you can have it send a message to the page it's being included in. window.parent in the iframe will be equivalent to window in the main page.

So to send a value back, add this code to the main page:

```
function childCallback(value) {

}
```

and this to the page in the iframe:

```
parent.childCallback(document.getElementsByName('syc')[0].value);
```